# WPF Datagrid - adding and deleting rows and MVVM

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, datagrid

If my `DataGrid` is bound to an MVVM property and the user deletes or adds a row to the grid, shouldn't it automatically add or delete the data from the `ObservableCollection` tied to it?

Do I have to do a command for this to work?   Does it not just work with just binding to the collection?

### XAML

```
<ExtendedGridControl:ExtendedDataGrid Grid.Row="5" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="6"  Margin="5,4,5,0"  ItemsSource="{Binding InvoiceDetailsForSelectedJobInvoice, Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <ExtendedColumn:ExtendedDataGridTextColumn Header="Description"  Width="200*" AllowAutoFilter="False"
                        Binding="{Binding Detail_Item_Description}" />
        <ExtendedColumn:ExtendedDataGridTextColumn Header="Unit" Width="50" AllowAutoFilter="False"
                        Binding="{Binding Detail_Item_Unit}" />
        <ExtendedColumn:ExtendedDataGridTextColumn Header="Unit Price" Width="70"
                        Binding="{Binding Detail_Item_Unit_Price}" AllowAutoFilter="False"/>
        <ExtendedColumn:ExtendedDataGridTextColumn Header="# of Units" Width="70"
                        Binding="{Binding Detail_Item_Number_Of_Units}"  AllowAutoFilter="False"/>
        <ExtendedColumn:ExtendedDataGridTextColumn Header="Discount %"
                        Binding="{Binding Detail_Item_Discount_Percentage}" Width="70" AllowAutoFilter="False"/>
        <ExtendedColumn:ExtendedDataGridTextColumn Header="Discount"
                        Binding="{Binding Detail_Item_Discount}" Width="70" AllowAutoFilter="False"/>
        <ExtendedColumn:ExtendedDataGridTextColumn Header="Total" Width="70"
                        Binding="{Binding Detail_Item_Total_Price}" AllowAutoFilter="False"/>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Revenue Allocation"  Width="100*"
                                SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Service_That_Revenue_Is_Allocated_To}"
                                DisplayMemberPath="ServiceName" SelectedValuePath="ServiceID"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource source}}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</ExtendedGridControl:ExtendedDataGrid>
```

### View Model

```
public class InvoiceViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<InvoiceDetail> InvoiceDetailsForSelectedJobInvoice
    {
        get
        {
            if (_selectedInvoice != null)
            {
                _invoiceDetails = new ObservableCollection<InvoiceDetail>(_selectedInvoice.InvoiceDetails);
                return _invoiceDetails;
            }
            return null;
        }
        set
        {
            _invoiceDetails = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("InvoiceDetailsForSelectedJobInvoice");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Two-Way Binding Mode?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean... like right out of the box, no commands.  If the user deletes the row, I want it deleted from the collection

Comment: Can we see some code for how you are binding the ObservableCollection to the DataGrid?

Comment: I would check the runtime output for errors. Maybe your delete command isn't being fired due to bad view-viewmodel wiring.

Comment: Edited showing the offending code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went ahead and used a `BindingList` instead of an `ObservableCollection` in my view model, it seems to work for what I need.

Answer (score 1):

`DataGrid`s do not automatically do that with observable collections. The deletes are held in memory and you have to hook into the `CollectionChanged` event to inspect inserts and deletions.

It's all spelled out here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30905/WPF-DataGrid-Practical-Examples#updates

Comment: I went ahead and used a BindingList instead of an ObservableCollection...  seems to work for what I need.