# VB.net, WPF and nested Datamodel: Best way to write back into Database?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, ms-access, datagrid

I'm pretty new to VB.net and WPF. However I have some experience in mainly PHP and JAVA programming. I managed to push myself through most of the traps that came across my way but now I have stumbled over something for which I belive there must be already a smart way to solve.

Here is what I mean:

I'm using VB.net, WPF and a MS Access Database. This is not negotiable and I'm not able to use another database. My Datamodel consists of serveral nested objects like this:

```
Public Class subSubObject
    Public Property id as int32
    Public Property description as string
End Class

Public Class subObject
    Public Property id as int32
    Public Property description as string
    Public Property subSubObjects as list (of subSubObject)
End Class

Public Class MainObject
    Public Property id as int32
    Public Property description as string
    Public Property subObjects as list (of subObject)
End Class

Public Class DataModel
    Public Property MainObjects as list (of MainObject)
End Class
```

I'm using an OLEDB connection to read the information from the database and create the corresponding objects to reflect my database model. So on this moment Database and Datamodel are identical.
Now I use a WPF datagrid with row details to perfom changes to the datamodel. This means I delete Objects, create new Objects and new Sub-Objects etc. The IDs are managed by the database engine and not by the application. I if I enter a new Dataset into the Database it will get a new ID autmatically.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgDataModel" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="true" CanUserAddRows="true" ItemsSource="{Binding DataModel}">

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>

                            <DataGrid x:Name="dgMainObjects"  
                                AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MainObjects}"         
                                IsReadOnly="False">

                                <DataGrid.Columns>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Path=ID}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Path=Description}" />
                                </DataGrid.Columns>

                                <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <DataGrid  x:Name="dgRegelsaetze" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=subObjects}">

                                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Path=ID}"/>
                                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description}" />
                                            </DataGrid.Columns>

                                            <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate>

                                                    <DataGrid x:Name="dgSubSubObjects"
                                                        AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubSubObjects}">

                                                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                                                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Path=RegelID}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                                                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Beschreibung" Binding="{Binding RegelBeschr}" />
                                                        </DataGrid.Columns>

                                                </DataTemplate>                             
                                        </DataGrid> 
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>

                            </DataGrid>

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>

                </DataGrid>

            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>
```

This code will not work. It's just to give you an idea how the application is built. Now after I changed the datamodel using the wpf datagrid I have to write the changes back to the database. Mostly there is no problem about that. I just do regular INSERT and UPDATE operations. But I noticed that the delete operations are the problems here. This is because after I deleted an Object by pressing DEL in the datagrid it is gone leaving no sign it ever existerd. As there is no ID or anything else left I'm not able to create the needed DELETE operations in SQL.

So I tried to solve this by using the CommandManager.PreviewExecuted property of the datagrids. It would give me the opportunity to define a sub that would catch a deleted Object and save it in a seperate list. I could use this list to create the DELETE commands later. At least that was my idea.

Unfortunately I found out that the command is run for every level of the cascade. So when I delete let's say an instance of subSubObject in the third level of my datagrid the sub is fired for alle the lower levels as well. So I'm ending up with a list that is not only filled with the deleted objects but with all it's parent objects as well.

To be honest I can't belive that the deleteion process is so complicated. I don't think I'm the first person ever with this problem so there must be an elegant way to solve this. Does anyone of you have an idea?

Thanks in advance.
Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using an ObservableCollection for MainObjects collection, you'll have to handle the CollectionChanged event. Looks like you could also change to a BindingList.

[StackOver reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12629281/wpf-datagrid-adding-and-deleting-rows-and-mvvm) to switching to a BindingList

[CodeProject article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30905/WPF-DataGrid-Practical-Examples#delete) referenced in the above StackOverflow post for handling deletes with the ObservableCollection CollectionChanged event.

Comment: Hi,that Answer gave me the right hint. What I did now was adding a "deleted-items-collection" to each of my classes. Then I used the collectionChanged event to put a copy of the deleted object in that collecion. Now I was able to use them to create my DELETE-Statement. I just was not familiar enough with events.